# Cast InputType object in GraphQL (Apollo)

Tags: java, graphql, apollo

I've this type of list (Address is my java class):

```
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

public class Address {
...
}
```

And I've to execute this type of request:

```
apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
        .serverUrl(mContext.getString(R.string.graphqlUrl))
        .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
        .addCustomTypeAdapter(CustomType.LISTOFMAPTOOBJECT, new AddressCustomTypeAdapter().customTypeAdapter())
        .build();

apolloClient.mutate(
        UpdateProfileAddressesMutation.builder()
                .addresses(?)
                .build()
).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<UpdateProfileAddressesMutation.Data>() {
...
});
```

But I'don't know what I've to send as parameters in **.addresses(?)**. This method asks me to send an ArrayList of AddressInput that is a graphql class autogenerate.

```
public final class AddressInput implements InputType { ... }
```

How can I convert my Address in AddressInput?

If I try something like

```
AddressInput ad = new AddressInput();
```

I've the following error "Cannot be accessed from outside package"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated input type has a builder method that can be used to instantiate it, so your code would look something like:

```
// Java
AddressInput address = AddressInput
  .builder()
  .city("San Francisco")
  .state("CA")
  .build();

// Kotlin
val address = AddressInput
  .builder()
  .city("San Francisco")
  .state("CA")
  .build()
```

If any of the fields inside of `AddressInput` also are input object types, you'll need to build each of them in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Just a note: I use java and I've to write AddressInput.builder() without new to let the code works.